# Windows 10 Custom Credential Provider: Authenticate without Windows password

Tags: windows, credential-providers

Is it possible using Custom Credential Provider to make windows logon without real password of local user?

I'm already able to install/register sample code from Microsoft, and even able to debug it.

My expectation from this mechanism: User inputs some password and my implementation  performs some comparison against local database of my password (stored as sqlite database).

Reality: local user password MUST be passed to LSA subsystem within 
`ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization(...)`

Frankly speaking I'm trying to use some sort of -one-time-coupon codes as passwords, to login to a kiosk-like workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main reason for developing custom credential provider.

Your provider must return to the `Logon UI` or `Cred UI` the authentication information. It can be a login/password pair or a certificate based authentication.

Inside of your database you can store a real user's password and return it after checking your own OTP.