# Bypass WinLogon programmatically

Tags: windows, credential-providers, winlogon

I have a service running into the PC that can spawn exe (usually games) remotely from internet. This works perfectly once the user has logged into their computer.

If the Windows Login (WinLogon) is present the exe won't launch (or will launch but won't be shown to the user). That is why I'd like to be able to bypass the Windows Login (WinLogon) programmatically.

I've tried the Registry Hack to autologin a said user. This works well but requires the user to either to never have a WinLogon or to reboot the PC to apply the patch (no Hot Patching).

The target Windows OS is Windows 10. I've seen that GINA api on microsoft is deprecated on Windows 10 (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-gina) and we should use a Credential Providers (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows)

What I would like to do but I'm not sure if it's possible is to trigger a Custom Windows Login from a SSO Token (the service provides this) that will then be checked using our Custom Credential Providers to our SSO Auth Servers and then let the user login.

From what i've seen this should be doable but I could not find any real good samples/documentation. MSDN documentations and sample is a bit lacking

Thanks a lot
Romain

Comment: Have a look at this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57121718/3868464) and the second [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57161384/3868464)